# Unable to import light-curve in sunpy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import 'lightcurve' in sunpy. But unfortunately got an error

> cannot import name 'lightcurve'

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Show us the full import statement.

Answer (score 0):

first make sure the module is installed, open the command line (search cmd in start menu) then type

```
pip install lightcurve
```

Or if your on Linux open the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

then import the module like this into your code

```
import lightcurve
```

Answer (score 0):

sunpy removed the lightcurve submodule and it was replaced with "timeseries".

An example of this is here: https://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/generated/gallery/time_series/goes_hek_m25.html#sphx-glr-generated-gallery-time-series-goes-hek-m25-py

I would suggest that if you found a example or resource that uses lightcurve that is very old, that it is out of date and is fit for use.
The latest documentation is https://docs.sunpy.org/en/stable/